# Remove right and left border of selected box

Tags: css

Remove right and left border of selected box with css without javascript is that possible ? min 2 boxes, max 5 or more boxes

for example;

I have 2 boxes. Only first box has right border. I want to do;
whichever is selected or hover, border must disappeared. 
look my image [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrkAW.png)

Comment: previous element can't be selected with CSS - following sibilings can be...

Comment: I would suggest you to search for `CSS previous sibling selector`. There's no real way to do with CSS but there's some tricks out there that you may adapt to your own code.

Comment: Yes as a trick I currently use flex with order.. But I wondered if there could be a better way.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with borders of hover'ed boxes. Idea is when you hover on any box, you do:

1. Left border color set the same as the background color: `border-left: 1px solid orange;`
2. set negative left margin equal to border width, that makes box to shift left over previous element and hide previous border: `margin-left: -1px;`
3. To prevent all the next boxes a notable shift, you need to increase active box width to its width + border width: `width: calc(20% + 1px);`
4. If padding is set inside the box, you need to add border width to left padding value.

Here is a solution (suggest a border-right width = 1px):

```css
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.box {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.box:not(:first-child):hover {
  border-left: 1px solid orange;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: calc(20% + 1px);
}
.box:hover {
  background: lightblue;
  border-right: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="box">box1</div>
<div class="box">box2</div>
<div class="box">box3</div>
<div class="box">box4</div>
<div class="box">box5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain this? I don't get how this is related to the question.

Comment: Q requirement is: If any of boxes has hovered, right border of first one should desappear. right?

Comment: Well, I guess it's up to the OP to check if that works. I'm just focused on the `CSS previous sibling selector`. :)

Comment: it is good but what if more boxes come? for example 5 box.. 
and 3. hover;
should not borders left and right at 3. box

Comment: I could not use CSS previous sibling selector :(

Comment: So please, why don't you ask exactly what you need.

Comment: @ceren - I think that if you really need to style it that way, you need to use `id`s or JavaScript. CSS doesn't has anything for going back, only forward. For example, styling a element's parent. Nope.

Comment: solution for any quantity of boxes is easy, but a little tricky. I'll change an answer in a moment.

Comment: I've changed an answer. Have a look.

Comment: thanks all :)  @user7393973